# Expression pattern of type 'String' cannot match values of type 'NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift4

I'm trying to convert my Swift 3 code to Swift 4. I get this error message:

> Expression pattern of type 'String' cannot match values of type 'NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier

This is my code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {

        case "showVC1":
            // DO SOMETHING
            break

        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Which type should I use instead of "String"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 4 switched the type of `identifier` property from `String?` to [`NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier?`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstoryboardsegue/1409578-identifier). The type is [`RawRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable), `RawType` of `String`. You may need to change your code to a chain of `if` statements, or use `rawValue` explicitly:

```
switch segue.identifier {
    case let x where x.rawValue == "showVC1":
        // DO SOMETHING
    break
    default:
    break
}
```

Comment: @MartinR I don't have access to Swift 4 yet, answering from the spec. I removed the part of the answer that suggested the `==` was possible. On an unrelated note, I'm really surprised that Apple went for a breaking change in this area: I can't think of a benefit to derive from changing `identifier` from `String` to its own type. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Similar changes were made for other "identifier strings", such as `NSImage(named: NSImage.Name)`. If I remember correctly, it was (controversially) discussed on one of the Swift mailing lists. I'll try to find some reference later, the list archives are currently offline. I find it strange that this change did not go through an proposal process, at least I can not remember that.

Comment: I have found the reference, see updated answer below.

Answer (score 8):

As of Swift 4, the storyboard identifier is a optional `NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier`, which is defined as

```
extension NSStoryboardSegue {
    public struct Identifier : RawRepresentable, Equatable, Hashable {
        public init(_ rawValue: String)
        public init(rawValue: String)
    }
}
```

You can switch on its `rawValue`:

```
    switch segue.identifier?.rawValue {
    case "showVC1"?:
        // do something ...
    default:
        break
    }
```

The *recommended pattern* however is to define constants for each
storyboard identifier:

```
extension NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier {
    static let showVC1 = NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier("showVC1")
    // other storyboard identifiers ...
}
```

which can then be matched against:

```
    switch segue.identifier {
    case .showVC1?:
        // do something ...
    default:
        break
    }
```

In both examples, the "optional pattern" `x?` (a shortcut for `.some(x)`)
is used to match against an optional value.

Similar types were introduced for other "identifiers", e.g. 
`NSImage.Name`, which is the argument type of `NSImage(named:)`
in Swift 4.

For more information, see the discussion on the swift-users mailing
list, starting at

- [[swift-users] What is up with names not being Strings any more in    Swift 4?](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20170717/005927.html).

The general idea (as I understand it) is to create separate types
for each kind of identifier. In particular (from https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20170717/005940.html):

> ... We are deliberately discouraging the string literal of the name. The string literal should be in only one place: the definition of the name constant. Everything else should use the constant. The compiler can provide autocompletion and typo detection of the constant. The string literal doesn't get that.