# NSCollectionView, Swift 4 - Cannot invoke "register"

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

Can anyone suggest how to solve this `NSCollectionView` issue? Converted from Swift 3 to Swift 4 and magic started happening :)

**Code:**

```
let item = NSNib(nibNamed: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "MACollectionViewItem"), bundle: nil)
collectionView.register(item, forItemWithIdentifier: "CollectionViewItem")
```

**Error for the second line:**

> Cannot invoke '`register`' with an argument list of type `'(NSNib?, forItemWithIdentifier: String)'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Swift 4, you need to use `NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier` instead of a `String` to identify a user interface element.

You should define static constants for identifiers and reference them when registering nibs.

**Example:**

```
extension NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier {
    static let collectionViewItem = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("CollectionViewItem")
}

collectionView.register(item, forItemWithIdentifier: .collectionViewItem)
```

Comment: You can also define static constants for the identifiers, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/45520652/1187415 for a similar issue. As I understand it, that is the recommended pattern.

Comment: My point is that you can now define a NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier static type property instead of a String constant.

Comment: Thanks for such a swift answer! Love Swift after Objective C, Swift 3 was really good, but looks like Swift 4 is not getting easier :)

Comment: @spacecash21: Did you notice that you already use the same technique in your `NSNib(nibNamed: NSNib.Name(rawValue:...))` ?

Comment: Yes I did :) Change is inevitable, hard to adjust :D Will get used to it in a week or two :)

Comment: This answer isn't working with whatever version of Swift is in Xcode 10. I get a compiler error: "Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads"

Comment: @Bryan Just checked it, this still works with Swift 4.2. I'd suggest checking your syntax again.

Comment: Thanks Tamás. The project's Swift version was incorrectly changed to 3, which is what caused this failure. It does indeed work in 4.2