# Why does Apple choose to use nested struct types to replace 'String' type parameter?

Tags: swift, struct, parameters, nested-types

For example:

Before new version of Swift,I could write like this:

```
NSNib(nibNamed: "TagCellView", bundle: nil)
```

Now Apple is choosing to define a lots of nested struct types,like `NSNib.Name`,and now I have to write like this:

```
NSNib(nibNamed: NSNib.Name("TagCellView"), bundle: nil)
```

IMHO I think the old version is much cleaner, what's the reason behind Apple's choice?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/45520652/1187415 for a similar issue and references to the Swift mailing list explaining the rationale.

Comment: @Martin, that actually doesn't apply as that is a new, concrete struct type, and thus it makes sense there.  `NSNib.Name` however is just an alias for `String` so none of the benefits of a concrete type apply.  Even extending `NSNib.Name` as shown below is really extending `String`. Further, functions that take `NSNib.Name` can take a string directly because again, it *is* a string, and likewise, functions that take a string can now take a `NSNib.Name` even if they have nothing to do with nibs.  If it were a concrete type it would be different, but without it, I can't see any benefit to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is to avoid scattering strings throughout your code. What you should do is define your constant for a given nib just once in your code. Then anywhere you need to use that nib name, you reference that one constant instead of retyping (possibly incorrectly) the hardcoded string.

You can define something like:

```
public struct MyNibs {
    public static let TagCellView = NSNib.Name("TagCellView")
}
```

And then use it as:

```
let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: MyNibs.TagCellView, bundle: nil)
```

Even cleaner is to add the constant as an extension to `NSNib.Name`:

```
extension NSNib.Name {
    public static let TagCellView = NSNib.Name("TagCellView")
}
```

Then your use is shorter:

```
let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: .TagCellView, bundle: nil)
```

This way you only enter the hardcoded string `"TagCellView"` once in your codebase. Everywhere else in your code you use `MyNibs.TagCellView`. If you rename the nib in Interface Builder, you only need to update one line of code instead of several.

Of course nothing prevents you from typing `NSNib.Name("TagCellView")` everywhere you need to reference that nib but the extra baggage may be incentive to create a constant.

Comment: Not sure I agree with this answer for two reasons. One, `NSNib.Name` is not a type. It's an alias for `String` so in your example above where you're extending `NSNib.Name`, you're actually extending String. Any function that takes a `String` can take `.TagCellView` so it's not scoped just to nib usage. As for keeping scattered literals out of your code, again, you could simply extend `String`, or better, like your first example, define a class called `MyNibs` and expose a static `tagCellView` `String` variable. It doesn't clutter up `String`'s api but still keeps your nib names together.

Comment: Point being there's no real use/need for this alias as it doesn't add anything, nor does it clarify anything, and since it's not a concrete type, it doesn't restrict anything either. If anything, like the OP said, it just confuses things.  Had they made it a concrete type (like the linked article in the comment on the original question), I would 100% agree with the change, but without it, I can't think of a single benefit to adding it and would love to be proven wrong here as it means I'd learn something I didn't know. :)